# How to compare a symbol typed in by a user with another symbol?

Tags: c++

I've tried with comparing char variable with a symbol in "" and it sais:

```
ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
```

Here is full code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a, b;
    char c;
    std::cin >> a >> c >> b;
    if (c == "+"){
        std::cout << (a + b);
    }
    if (c == "-"){
        std::cout << (a - b);
    }
    if (c == "*"){
        std::cout << (a * b);
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Side note: if `c` is +, it can't possibly be - or *. You can save a bit of time with `else if` or a `switch`/`case`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"c"` results in a character array or what we call a C-string, which is not what you want. If you want to have an expression which represents a single character use `'c'` instead!

The code becomes:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a, b;
    char c;
    std::cin >> a >> c >> b;
    if (c == '+'){
        std::cout << (a + b);
    }    
    if (c == '-'){
        std::cout << (a - b);
    }    
    if (c == '*'){
        std::cout << (a * b);
    }    
}
```

As reading the other answer here: You should decide to use string to string compare or character to character compare. Mixing it up will simply not work out of the box.

Comment: This would also be a good place for a `switch` statement.

Comment: @KeithThompson: or else/if or ... :-)

Comment: One thing to point out is that `>>` with a `char` does not strip any leading whitespace. So if user inputs `3 +4` then you won’t have what you expect in `c`.

Comment: soooo, you should have `std::cin >> a >> std::ws >> c >> b;`